# How do I use Optimization, interpolation, objective with a function of arbitrary order?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, curve-fitting

I would like to do a non-linear interpolation for a polynomial function of arbitrary order. Using scipy.optimize and curve_fit I can define an objective like

```
def objective(x, p_0, p_1, p_2):
    return p_0 + p_1 * x + p_2 * np.power(x,2)
```

but this is not what I need. I would like to have the choice case by case which order the function needs. Something like

```
p = np.array([0,0,0])
def objective(x, p ):
    res = np.sum(p[i]*np.power(x,i) for i in range(3))
    return res
```

came to my mind but it doesn't work. I would like to freely decide to have instead of 3 a 10 or whatever which would be an additional argument for the function. Meanwhile I'm not too convinced that *curve_fit* is the best choice.

Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: I think you are looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55132107/scipy-fitting-with-parameters-in-a-vector

Comment: Numpy has a `Polynomial` class with an implemented fitting routing: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.polynomials.html#quick-reference

Comment: Yep, @Mr.T is right, especially as this is a linear fit, so `curve_fit()` for non-linear fitting is not required.

Comment: @Mr.T yes, thanks. I used *Polynomial* for this case. Nevertheless, I would like to understand it for a nonlinear case, too.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply you could modify the function in your example to take a third parameter:

```
p = np.array([0,0,0])
def objective(x, p, n):
    res = np.sum(p[i]*np.power(x,i) for i in range(n))
    return res
```

Parameter "n" is just the length of the p array / the number of p inputs.

Comment: Could you please show a working example with *curve_fit* using your code? The problem is that it does accept only a function (= callable) and then scalars which stand for the parameters. I didn't manage to make your code run.

Comment: sounds like the number of loops is handled by the curve_fit function then. try just passing curve_fit the required input - the scalar parameters?